# Certbot/LetsEncrypt privacy error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've installe a SSL on my server to protect my domain, now the thing that's happening is that I get this error in Chrome etc:

> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from example.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

So I figured out that it has something to do with the `chain`, but I have no clue on how to fix this.

The command I used to install the SSL: `./certbot-auto certonly --standalone --email pligthart@live.nl -d leeshetetiket.nl -d www.leeshetetiket.nl -d product.leeshetetiket.nl`

I'm running `nginx` on an Ubuntu server.

I hope someone has a solution to this.

Comment: Paste your nginx config about ssl.

Comment: Do you mean my `conf` file on the domain, where the vhosts are? @Lution

Comment: yes. Need to check if you have configured ssl right. @Peurr

Comment: @Lution I don't think I did, I only installed the certificate, can't find out how to add the vhost.. I have not worked with nginx before..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic nginx ssl config example

```
    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name   example.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    }
```

You will have to config in your config file for virtual host to enable ssl and config the correct cert file for https to work.

Check to nginx docs [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).